# CGFloat from a float?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

How do you cast or create a CGFloat from a float?

I get a bad receiver type float * error.

```
CGFloat point = [graphValues objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: What is graphValues? objectAtIndex? Not enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the array is not an `NSArray` but a `float` array.

```
CGFloat point = graphValues[0];
```

If you want to know how `CGFloat` is declared, have a look in the header (it should be a `double`).

Answer (score 3):

`graphValues` is probably not an `NSArray`, but a C-array of `float`s. If so, you want this:

```
CGFloat point = graphValues[0];
```

(The reason I think this is because it's telling you you're trying to call an Objective-C method on a `float *`.)